# Projectile motion: Distance, speed, and angle?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, angle, projectile-motion

A ball is thrown eastward into the air from the origin (in the direction of the positive x-axis). The initial velocity is 
$60 i + 64 k$,
 with speed measured in feet per second. The spin of the ball results in a southward acceleration of $4 ft/s^2$, so the acceleration vector is $a = −4 j − 32 k$. How far does the ball land from the origin, and what is its angle and speed when it hits the ground?

I got 186.6 ft from the origin, and I'm pretty sure I just need to plug the time into the velocity function and find the norm of it to get its speed. I don't know how to go about solving the angle, though.

Comment: You have two components of velocity before it hits the ground. These components are orthogonal to each other, and form a right triangle.

Comment: Am I supposed to use the initial velocity's components to find the angle between them? I ended up getting 22.3 degrees, which was wrong.

Comment: No, you want the components of your final velocity.

Comment: Something isn't adding up then, as my velocity components when t = 4 (the time when the ball hits the ground) are 60i - 16j - 64k, but this doesn't satisfy the Pythagorean Theorem.